# Safari Extension multiple start script inclusion

Tags: safari, safari-extension

I am building a simple Safari extension and sometimes the start script `start.js` specified is never included ans sometimes it is included many times like so :

[image]

Has it ever happened to you ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably due to iframes. The injected script is loaded in every iframe in the current tab. I don't think you can stop the script itself loading, but you can use `if (window == window.top)` within the script to ensure that code is only executed in the main page, not the contained iframes.

Comment: Ok, I'll try this and I get back :) Thanks